# How to ensure words are evenly spaced when they feature a different number of characters w/ CSS?

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYr6s.jpg

I'm tinkering with the CSS grid system and am in the process of making a simple nav bar. (I'm aware flexbox is probably better suited for the task).

The buttons are titled: Work, Resume and Projects in that order.

My problem is that because Resume and Projects have a higher character count than Work, when sizing down to mobile, Work gets a nice even spacing with enough margin on it's left side, but Projects ends up being forced further toward the right and ends up off-center. They've all been given 1fr of the space each. Can I somehow make it dynamically scale?

I'm thinking perhaps I could introduce a media query to size down the font below a certain width and everything will be fine, but would appreciate any other suggestions as I'd prefer things to be large and "touchable" at that screen size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are giving a fixed width or min-width for your buttons, please remove it and instead add a padding left and right to a certain value, maybe 1rem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said - flexbox is much better suited to what you are trying to achieve. If you still want to use grid, you should know that the spaces between words of different length can't be equal unless you give appropriate lengths to the different columns.
This is the best I was able to achieve:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
}
.item {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">WORK</div>
  <div class="item">RESUME</div>
  <div class="item">PROJECTS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Appreciate the example greatly and thanks for the trouble- I might not end up with grid as a final solution though your explanation really helped to frame what's actually going on.